# Getting Flex Builder to use a Tomcat server on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, flexbuilder

I'm currently trying to get a Tomcat server I have running in Eclipse on http ://localhost:8080/ to be noticed through Flex Builder 4.  I think it may have to do with the config.xml file in my Flex Builder project.  It is currently set as the following (as well as some other stuff)

```
<config>
 <server>
 http://localhost:8080/myty/myy?p1=a1
 </server>
 <iroot>
 c:</iroot>
 <oroot>
 c:</oroot>
```

I think it may be that I am using a Mac and there is no C drive on a Mac. However, I think it may also be the server location. I tried taking the part after 8080 out, but then I just get errors and nothing happens as opposed to the actual server page showing up.

Comment: What do you mean by "Noticed"? Do you mean to have Flex Builder attach to the Tomcat you have running on Eclipse, or are you trying to connect a Flex program to Tomcat?

Comment: I mean to have Flex Builder attach to the Tomcat server so that I am able to deploy programs in flex builder that can use data on the tomcat server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lcds or blazeds to push your application to an app server like tomcat. I haven't tried configuring my installation of tomcat to it. But I have worked with the tomcat installation that lcds provides. Works fine.

You can read up on configuring tomcat to lcds here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/es/lcds_installation.html#tomcat

Let me know how it goes